# Why $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n}} = \infty$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Could you please explain to me why this is true:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n}} = \infty$$

I have tried L'Hôpital's rule, but it doesn't add any clarification.

Comment: well, you can find the logarithm of the numerator  and then the logarithm of the denominator.

Comment: That is so true. So, it would look like this: n/sqrt(n)log(sqrt(n)). If n approaches infinity the numerator will dominate the denominator, right? Btw, thank you very much for editing.

Comment: well...  there is a natural equivalent expression  for $ \log \sqrt n $

Comment: I would instead find the logarithm of the entire expression and show that that logarithm tends to infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series $$\sum {\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}}\over 2^n}$$ is convergent due to the $n$-th root test. Indeed we get $${{\sqrt{n}^{1\over\sqrt{n}}\over 2}}\to{1\over 2}$$ Hence the general term tends to $0,$ and its reciprocal to $+\infty.$

On the way we have used a well known fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1$ which follows easily from  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1/n}=1$ basing on $(1+\delta)^n\ge  {n(n-1)\over 2}\delta^2,$ for $\delta>0.$

Comment: This implies that f(n) = ω(g(n)). Am I correct?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint.**

$\bullet~ \frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt n ^{\sqrt n}} = \left( \frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$

$\bullet$ $2^x > 2x$ holds for $x\geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n}}
&=\dfrac{2^n}{(n^{1/2})^\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\dfrac{2^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}/2}}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{2}{n^{1/\sqrt{n}}}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}^{2/\sqrt{n}}}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\dfrac{2}{\left(\sqrt{n}^{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2}\right)^n\\
\end{array}
$

and since

$(1+n^{-1/2})^n
\ge 1+n^{1/2}
\gt n^{1/2}
$
(by Bernoulli)
so,
raising to the
$2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n}
\lt 
(1+n^{-1/2})^2
\lt 1+3n^{-1/2}
$
so,
putting $n^{1/2}$ for $n$,

$\sqrt{n}^{1/\sqrt{n}}
\lt 1+3n^{-1/4}
\lt 1+\frac14$
for large enough $n$
so

$\dfrac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n}}
\gt \left(\dfrac{2}{(5/4)^2}\right)^n
=\left(\dfrac{32}{25}\right)^n
\to \infty
$

for large enough $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Comment: This implies that f(n) = ω(g(n)). Am I correct?